# Dual booting mint and windows 10 on SSD + Sata

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, dual-boot

I have Windows 10 on SSD partition(1TB) and Linux Mint on Sata (1TB). But while booting, the system boots into Windows 10 only. I used supergrub disk and could see Mint Linux in the entries, which when clicked it boots into Mint.
My questions are:

1. Can I overwrite windows boot with mint ? If yes then how?
2. Can I use supergrub to do this?

[image]

[image: Can't see second hard disk]

[image]

Can't even see second hard disk . How do I even boot into it then ?
Changed SATA mode, still second hard disk not showing

Comment: please append the output of `sudo ls /boot/efi` and `efibootmgr -v`

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know but I think if you overwrite the Windows Boot Manager you can't boot in Windows anymore. But you can change in your UEFI/BIOS the default Hard Disk from which you boot. Now you boot in Linux Mint and type in the command:

`sudo update-grub`

Now somewhere should be a line which looks like this:

```
Found Windows [Version] (Loader) on /dev/{hard disk of the Windows Installation}
```

Now you can reboot your computer and see in the GRUB menu a entry to the Windows Boot Manager. If you choose it you should see your Windows booting.

Comment: Hmm that seems reasonable way. WIll try and update

Comment: Cant even see second hard disk in BIOS . How do I even boot into it then ? Changed SATA mode, still second hard disk not showing. have added the pics, pls help

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that because the windows disk has an EFI partition that you're booting with secure boot.

1. make sure you installed grub in EFI mode - boot into mint, check for the EFI files:

   `sudo su -
   cd /boot/efi
   ls`
    If there is nothing there (or the directory doesn't exist), you have probably not mounted the EFI partition, so you're going to need to mount it (this also means you likely haven't installed in EFI mode).
   `mkdir -p /boot/efi
   mount -t vfat /dev/sdXY /boot/efi`
    where `X` is the drive letter as indexed by linux (not windows) and `Y` is the partition number of the EFI partition.  You will also need to add this mount to `/etc/fstab`, but ***DO NOT*** use the `/dev/sdXY` path when appending to `/etc/fstab`, instead use `blkid` to get the UUID of the partition, so the entry should look like:

   `UUID=1234-ABCD  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1`

   if the partition has a UUID of `1234-ABCD` (yours will almost certainly be different).

   If there is something there when you `ls` (there should at least be a directory named "Microsoft" - where the windows EFI files sit) but there is no other directory, you haven't installed grub in EFI mode, so:

   `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id="grub" --recheck --debug`
2. make sure the UEFI firmware accepted the boot entry (from mint, use `efibootmgr -v` to see the listings - and for your own good, I ***strongly*** suggest you read the manual).  If there is no entry like "ubuntu", "grub", "linux", "debian", or the like, then you have no EFI entry for grub, so add it:

   `efibootmgr -c -g -d /dev/sdX -p Y -w -L "grub" -l /EFI/grub/grubx64.efi`
    where `X` is the drive letter as indexed by linux (not windows) and `Y` is the partition number of the EFI partition.
3. make sure the UEFI firmware accepts either shim's or grub's EFI signature as valid and that it will boot to it when manually chosen
4. go back into mint, disable the windows boot (do not remove it or windows, being the schizophrenic only child that it is, will write itself to the top of the list again) by using

   `efibootmgr -b X -A`
   where X is the number of the windows boot

   `efibootmgr -o Z` where Z is the number of the grub EFI entry

And finally, when all that's done, `sudo update-grub`, then reboot - if you did it right, you should have a grub boot screen with all the OSs available on the system in a list.

Other resources: [Debian's article on UEFI](https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI) and [Archlinux's examples of grub with UEFI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/EFI_examples)

Comment: Cant see second hard disk in bios. Have added pics, pls help

Comment: updated with more detailed steps